# Is there a comparative form of the word "different?"

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

Does the adjective "different" have a comparative form? If so what is it?

Comment: I think the general rule is that only words of one syllable, and *some* two-syllable words, can form superlatives by appending *-er* and *-est*. Arguably, "different" is two-and-a-half syllables, so it doesn't meet the requirement. The superlatives are therefore *more different*, and *most different*, to the extent that such terms can meaningfully be used as adjectival phrases.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/different#Adjective

Comment: Voting to reopen. I'm not sure how much can be added to John's answer, though I'd like to know if there's any more on the guiding principle as to *which* two-syllable words can take *-er, -est*. But just because Wiktionary happens to define the comparative doesn't mean this Q is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

There's no single word, no.

*Different* has three syllables, and English adjectives of three or more syllables (as **pronounced**, not spelled) must use the periphrastic *more* or *most* to form a comparative or superlative phrase.

The comparative suffix *-er* and superlative suffix *-est* can only inflect adjectives of one syllable, with a few -- mostly ones ending in /i/ or /o/ -- of two syllables swinging both ways.

- ***big***: *bigger, biggest,* **more big*, **most big*
- ***easy***: *easier, easiest, ?more easy, ??most easy*
- ***narrow***: *narrower, narrowest, more narrow, ?most narrow*
- ***helpful***: **helpfuller,* **helpfullest*, *more helpful, most helpful*
- ***interesting***: **interestinger*, **interestingest*, *more interesting, most interesting*

Just one more example of dying inflections in English. There are only 9 inflectional suffixes in English, and this is two of them, both hanging on only in common monosyllables.

Comment: Reference that there are no three-syllable cases?

Comment: Check any ESL textbook. Non-native speakers have to be taught the actual grammar of the language, instead of the catechism of shibboleths that native speakers are taught in Anglophone schools.

Comment: Your reply makes me unhappier than most.

Comment: @GEdgar: unfriendliest.   I'm cheating a little by adding the 'un', but just wanted to highlight that there is at least one exception to the rule.

Answer (score 2):

It’s *more different*, but it’s normally only used in  negative sentences, as in, for example, *Nothing could be more different than chalk and cheese*.