# "Much more easy" versus "much easier"

Tags: comparatives

My mom and I are having a dispute on *much more easy* versus *much easier*. For example, consider the sentence:

> It's [much more easy]/[much easier] to do action X than action Y.

I say that *much easier* is correct and that *much more easy* is grammatically incorrect, while she says that both are okay. I understand that both are acceptable colloquially, but which is grammatically correct here? If you could explain why, that would be even better!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["More clear" vs "Clearer": when to use "more" instead of "-er"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er)

Comment: Related: [Conundrum: “cleverer” or “more clever”, “simpler” or “more simple” etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc)

Answer (score 12):

The comparative (and superlative) in English are always morphological for words of **one** syllable:

- *harder, wider, smaller, bigger, older*

and periphrastic for words of **three** (or more) syllables:

- *more interesting, more successful, more suggestive, more polyglot*

It's the words of **two** syllables where we get into trouble:

- *more useful, more decent, more careful, more tender, more helpful*

**but**

- *easier, happier, sillier, narrower, simpler.*

Generally, if a two-syllable word ends in /i/ or /o/ (e.g, *easy, happy, silly, narrow*), then it gets the morphological *-er* and *-est*. Otherwise it's *more* and *most*.

Comment: There appears to be a change underway, though, whereby the analytic comparative is gradually gaining ground generally, e.g. "colder" > "more cold".

Comment: That's pretty much true of all inflections in English. Syntax has got **momentum** in English; we're in the power stroke of the [Grammaticalization Cycle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grammaticalization.pdf).

Comment: Does "much" out front make a difference?  Eg one might usually prefer "easier" to "more easy" but still prefer "much more easy" to "much easier".

Comment: Different people have different preferences, and variations; the rhythm of _much more easy_ might appeal to some, in some contexts, more than the rhythm of _much easier_. Or vice versa. This is a grey area, as Neil points out above.

Comment: "tenderer" and "tenderest" are just about ok, and are used (perhaps rarely, admittedly) -- probably because "tenderer" is a noun as well.

Comment: That's a different _-er_ morpheme, with different morphology. My guess is that final /ər/, being a resonant like the /w/ and /y/ at the end of /i/ and /o/, can take the suffix. Similarly, _purpler_ is not as bad as it ought to be.

Comment: The words *purpler, littler, suppler, gentler* still end up being two syllables after the suffix; presumably this makes them more acceptable.

Comment: /əl/ is also a resonant like /ər/; they act in many of the same ways and even [dissimilate](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Latin_dissimilation.pdf) with one another.

Answer (score 6):

Re: monosyllabic adjectives.

Sometimes, they take "more" and "most" (the following is based on *The Oxford guide to English usage*, 1994, and *The Cambridge grammar of the English language*, 2002):

- the following monosyllabic adjectives usually take "more" and "most": cross, fake, ill, like, loath, prime, real, right, worth, wrong;
- past participles (bored, drunk, lost etc.);
- in constructions of the type "more good than bad" or "more dead than alive";
- for stylistic reasons, e.g. "I am the more bad because I realize where my badness lies." (L.P. Hartley).

Martin Parrott (2000) adds one more case: when you want to make a specific contrast with 'less', e.g.:

A: *Did she say it was less cold in the north of the country?*

B: *No. She said it was more cold.*

Huddleston and Pullum 2002 argue that there is a difference between

(a) *Ed is older than middle-aged.* (his age is beyond middle age).

(b) *Ed is more old than middle-aged.* (metalinguistic comparison: Ed is more properly described as old than as middle-aged).

In the Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English, there is a section on **doubly marked comparatives and superlatives** (7.7.5), e.g.:

*She's a bit more nicer than Mrs. Jones* (CONV)

*It's much more warmer in there.* (CONV)

The authors of the Longman grammar - btw, it's descriptive, corpus-based - say that "such forms are stigmatized and generally considered unacceptable - unless they are used jokingly in Standard English" (p. 525).

cf. Celce-Murcia and Larsen-Freeman (1999): "double marking of comparatives is a developmental phenomenon that never completely disappears in the informal speech of some English users" (p. 729).

There is a excellent paper where doubly marked comparatives and superlatives are discussed at length - Solomon, G. 1994. *A more closer look at comparatives and superlatives*. Unpublished paper. UCLA.

Answer (score 5):

In a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51214/is-there-a-comparative-form-of-the-word-different), John Lawler wrote

> ***easy***: easier, easiest, ?more easy, ??most easy

to indicate that construction *more easy* is questionable, and *most easy* still more questionable.  However, there are cases where *easier* sounds worse to me than does *more easy*, particularly in cases like

> My heart is more easy now.
>   *My heart is easier now.

That is, when *easy* means *relieved* rather than *not difficult*, *more easy* and *most easy* seem better than  *easier* and *easiest*, and I think in such cases their use is not questionable.

In BlackJack's example ("It's [more easy]/[easier] to do X than Y"), I have no problem with either *more easy* or *easier*, and slightly prefer *easier*.

Comment: Thanks, jwpat7. I'd forgotten that one. And you're right about that sense of _easy_, because it's metaphoric and idiomatic.

Comment: I tend to agree: I have a difficult time conceiving how `much more easy` could be breaking a rule. Things like "more easier" don't really break a rule either, excepting perhaps the rule about avoiding redundant redundancy.

Answer (score -2):

In terms of casual  use , the forms easier/more easy tend to appear respectively by their difference on meaning; easier tends to appear in specific contexts where it means ' freed' or ' released' and 'more easy' is more likely to come up if it literally means ' less difficult ( than) '

HUDDLESTON AND PULLUM

Comment: If this is a quote, please use the > method to indicate that, and cite it. A bit of commentary of your own is always useful.