# "The likeliest problem" vs. "the most likely problem"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, writing-style, superlative-degree

*The likeliest problem* vs. *the most likely problem*:

- are they both correct?
- do they mean the same thing?
- is one preferable over another?

Comment: See [this response](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67991/much-more-easy-versus-much-easier/67993#67993) on the topic, one of many.

Answer (score 5):

They're both equally understandable and clear, they both mean the same thing, and they're both grammatically correct, but one is stylistically better (and, therefore, preferable). This is a style choice (personal judgment and preference prevail, in other words). My style is generally formal, so I prefer "the most likely problem"; "the likeliest problem" is casual and more appropriate for spoken English or for a letter to a friend. Superlatives with two-syllable words such as "likely" **usually** give the writer/speaker the choice of adding the /-est/ suffix or using "the most..." structure. One wouldn't say "the most big" (one-syllable word) but "the biggest", and one wouldn't say "the interestingest" (three-syllable word) but "the most interesting".

Comment: I sometimes choose phrasings that are less common to make my speech sound more interesting or to otherwise capture the reader's attention. I find that "likeliest" sounds okay enough and different enough from common speech that it accomplishes this. Subjectively, I don't find that it sounds informal, because I find that informal speech rings most familiarly in the ear. Rare speech can sound exclusive, elite or apropos of upper crust prattling.

Answer (score 4):

At first, **comparison of disyllabic adjectives is a very tricky thing** - cf. Palmer, Huddleston, and Pullum 2002: 1584 "there is no hard and fast boundary between those that can inflect and those that can't: speaker judgements are by no means wholly uniform." A good rule of thumb for **disyllabic adjectives** is that **the analytic forms** (with *more* and *most*) **are always possible**,  unlike the inflectional ones (with *-er* and *-est*).

However, adjectives ending in "-ly" *generally* permit inflection (PHP 2002: 1583). The authors of the "Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English" (LGSWE) make a very important addition to that statement, "**with varying degrees of frequency**" (Biber et al. 1999: 523). Quite often it's a matter of style/register (Weiner and Delahunty 1994).

To answer your specific question, Biber et al. argue that **with the adjective "likely**," **the analytic forms ("more likely") are much more common that the inflectional ones ("likelier")**, esp. in academic prose and in the news, where you're more likely to encounter the analytic forms in general.

Comment: Rules of thumb aren’t 100%: I’m not sure that the analytic form would be an acceptable alternative to the inflected one in cases such as *the earliest citation*, as *the ?most early citation* seems suspect. Whether that’s entirely because the underlying cranberry morphology is no longer transparent (insofar as it resists subtracting *‑ly* under a strictly synchronic analysis), I don’t know, especially given the existence of others of similarly non-transparent origin where an analytic version is probably more acceptable, such as with *holy, jolly, ugly, wily* (but *only* is different).