# -er rather than -lier as an adverbial comparative form

Tags: adverbs, comparatives, philology

In modern German, one can make *tief* into the comparative *tiefer,* regardless of whether the word is used as adjective or adverb.  In English, I now have a sentence in which I want to do the same thing with the English *deep,* because *more deeply* does not suit the cadence of my sentence and, frankly, *deeplier* looks dippy.  Can I do what I want?  Can I use *deeper* as an adverb?  Is this good usage?  Is it good philology?  Is it sanctioned by practice?  If so, why, please?  If not, why not?

My *Webster's Ninth New Collegiate Dictionary* surprisingly seems to offer no clue.

I realize that English occasionally allows the positive *deep* as an adverb, but such usage probably would be pretentious in my particular instance -- or, at best, would serve only to dodge the linguistic question.  If such dodging makes bad English in principle, then one prefers not to dodge.  It is not that I wish to convert the poetic adverb *deep* into *deeper,* but the more pedestrian adverb *deeply* into *deeper.*

(I do not know how interesting or relevant my specific sentence is to readers of this site, but if it interests you:  "Ideally, the professional mathematician knows or precisely specifies in advance -- or, deeper, reveals the very wisdom of -- the set of fundamental axioms he means to use to derive a result.")

Comment: Looks like General Reference to me. You can *breathe deeply*, but you can't *breathe deeper* unless there's a specified (or strongly implied) *less deep* breathing being compared against.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, this looks like general reference, but I cannot find the answer in general reference. Admittedly, my general references are dictionaries, which are probably insufficient for a grammar question. I know that *deep* is an adverb (*dig deep*), as well as an adjective (*a deep breath*).  I have used *deeper* as an adverb (*"We need you to breathe deeper"*), though perhaps in violation of *proper* grammar.

Comment: @Mike: Sure, *deeper* in your example is an "adverb". But it's a *comparative adverb* - in that case, *deeper than normal*, or *deeper than you're currently breathing*. OP's proposed usage is  of that general ilk, but as others have said, it's pretty awkward in his specific case. Prsonally, I think his entire parenthetical phrase is both grammatically and semantically a bad fit for the main sentence. And I have trouble working out why he sees *knows* and *precisely specifies in advance* as juxtaposable elements within the main sentence anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree entirely. Most importantly, I agree a rewrite would be preferable. I think he wants the superlative rather than the comparative adverb, but because *or* is used, the implication is that *knows* and *specifies* are two equivalent options, whereas I would consider them *standard* versus *good* behaviors for the professional.  I write such sentences and am quite empathetic with OP.

Comment: @Mike: You're ahead of me then. I'd have thought since our hypothetical mathematician might *know* the axioms himself, but fail to specify them to others, these two possibilities shouldn't be contrasted using *"or"* in the first place. And where to you draw the line between *"precisely specifies"* and *"reveals the very wisdom of"* (which strikes me as incredibly ungainly phrasing anyway)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use *deeper* as the comparative of the adverb *deep*. It was good enough for Milton (‘That they may stumble on, and deeper fall’), and for other writers too.

That said, the sentence as a whole doesn’t sound quite right. For one thing, it's unusual to follow *wisdom of* with a noun in that way, rather than with the *-ing* form of a verb.

Comment: To have asked you to rewrite the sentence for me would have been unreasonable.  However, since you yourself have mentioned it:  I first drafted that sentence a couple of years ago and have never really liked it.  It starts to go wrong from its first word.  Without spending much of your time, if a rewritten sentence occurred to you to suggest, I should be glad to read it.  (For information, in my manuscript, the sentence leads its subsection.  Nothing immediately precedes it.)

Comment: Well, only you know what effect you might want to achieve, and you will have a greater knowledge of the subject matter than I have, but you might like to consider something like:

‘Ideally, the professional mathematician will know which set of fundamental axioms he needs to use to achieve the desired result. He may even specify them precisely in advance or, at a somewhat deeper level, explain the rationale behind them.’

Comment: I came for advice on adverbs because that is what I had thought that I needed, but it seems that what I really needed was your helpful suggestion to replace my brittle, old sentence!  I have copied your rewrite into my draft and am now smoothing it into context.  I suspect that the old sentence, which had prompted the question, is a goner.

Comment: If your suggestion's issue interests you, an entirely rewritten paragraph has flowed rather naturally from it.  It reads much better now.  Moreover, I would like to think that I understand, or begin to understand, the *kind* of change your suggestion represents.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad that it helps. It's good that you rewrote the entire paragraph to ensure consistency of style.

Answer (score 4):

The comparative and superlative degrees of adverbs follow the same rules in English as those of adjectives do.

As for using *deep* as an adverb, you can certainly *delve deep*, and thus *delve deeper*.  If you were using *delve deeply*, though, you would have to use *delve more deeply*.   That’s because the only time you use a *‑y* > *‑ier* rule for forming comparative degrees of adjectives or adverbs is when it is a two-syllable word that is not an *‑ly* word.   (Everything I say in this posting regarding comparatives with *‑er* with also applies to superlatives with *‑est*.)

- For example, *artsy > artsier*,  *beefy > beefier*, *bossy > bossier*, *crazy > crazier*, *funny > funnier, edgy > edgier*, *mousy > mousier*, *phony > phonier*, *pretty > prettier* on the one hand.
- But on the other hand *aptly > more aptly*, *costly > more costly*, *coyly > more coyly*, *dryly > more dryly*, *gaily > more gaily*, *grisly > more grisly*, *hourly > more hourly*, *idly > more idly*, *kindly > more kindly*, *manly > more manly*, *mildly > more mildly*, *newly > more newly*, *simply > more simply*, *surely > more surely*, *truly > more truly*, *wryly > more wryly*.

Sometimes in informal speech you will hear *‑ly > -lier* in places where the “rule” says it should use the *“more ━ly”* version instead, like *hilly > ?hillier*, *silly > ?sillier*, *manly > ?manlier*.  I’m not even sure those are completely “wrong”.

Note very carefully that in words ending in *‑ly* for other reasons than to make a modifier out of another word with an *‑ly* suffix, that now again *‑ly > ‑lier* for two-syllable words.  So for example *holy > holier*,  *ugly > uglier*, *early > earlier*, *lonely* > *lonelier*.

Note also that *only* does not normally take inflections, so *?onliest* is considered informal.

Also, sometimes two competing forms exist, especially of adjectives, such as *friendly > friendlier* or *more friendly*, *homely > homelier* or *more homely*, *lively > livelier* or *more lively*, *sickly* > *sicklier* or *more sickly*.

Lastly, two-syllable *‑ey* words generally also go to *‑ier*, as in *cagey > cagier*, *choosey > choosier*, *dicey > dicier*, *nosey > nosier*, *pricey > pricier*.  One-syllable ones, however, do not: *fey > feyer*, *grey > greyer*.

Comment: see http://english.stackexchange.com/a/68870/19046

Comment: You'll probably find that e.g "grislier", "sillier" are pretty universally accepted. No reason to brand them as being "wrong" as far as I can see.

Comment: @NeilCoffey I used a question mark because I said I wasn’t sure. I think you are right with the “━ly” adjectives; also add to that *chilly, frilly*.  Oddly, I don’t think you would do the same with an adverb like *shrilly*, and I can’t see why.

Comment: This is an excellent, thorough, most informative answer, a better answer than my question deserved.  The answer merits an *acceptance* checkmark from me and a +2; except that, by Stackexchange's rules, I haven't got a second checkmark to give.  Accept the +1 and my thanks.